# JQuery Mobile não funciona em ambiente seguro (https)

Tags: jquery-mobile

Tenho um site do qual uma área dele está usando o certificado digital (https), porém o jquery mobile não funciona. Como eu faria para resolver isso? Segue abaixo como estou chamando:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile: Theme Download</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/pertutti.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

  <style media="screen">
  table { width:100%; border-spacing: 0; }
   th { text-align:left; }
   th h3 { margin:.6em 0 .6em .5em; }
   th, td { vertical-align:top; border-top:1px solid #eee; padding: 1px 3px; background-color:#fcfcfc; }
   td .ui-btn { margin:.4em 0 .5em 0; }
   td .ui-btn-inner { padding: .4em 15px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
....
```

Comment: É melhor incluir o seu código. Vão marcar a pergunta como não clara o suficiente ou ampla demais, e com razão.

Comment: Provavelmente a fonte que puxa o jquery-mobile é http. o que pode ser feito, baixar a biblioteca e incluir através de um path do seu aplicativo, ou procurar uma fonte que também seja https

Comment: Tem razão inova pixel. Coloquei o trecho como estou chamando o jquery mobile.

Comment: Inclua o s no final do http, essa [cdn](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js) possui certificado ssl também

Comment: Perfeito MarceloBoni. Funcionou! Obrigado!